# Why doesn't my program find the 10001st prime? [Project euler-problem7]

Tags: java, primes

My problem is my program doesn't find the 10001st prime. So it never stops and I still don't know the 10001st prime. I will be happy to solve the problem with my implementation. Thank you :)

```
public class problem7 {

    public static boolean sonuc=true;

    public static void asalmi(int j)
    {
        int counter=0;
        int asayac=0;

        for(int k=1;k<=j;k++)
        {
            if(j%k==0)
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter==2)
        {
            // Only factors are 1 and j, so j is prime
            System.out.println(j);
            asayac++;
            counter=0;
            if(asayac==10001)
            {
                System.out.println(j);
                sonuc=false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int i=1;
        while(sonuc)
        {
            asalmi(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't stop just because your program cannot reach 10001 prime in a short amount of time. You have to improve your algorithm

Comment: why should it quit? 10001 is composite: 73x137, and since your `for()` loop has incorrect boundaries, you're counting `1` and `10001` as factors as well, so `count` will be **4** for that number. Since you only test count==2, you never reach the `if(asayac=10001)`.

Comment: That's not quite true - he's not testing whether 10001 is prime, but looking for the 10001st prime - i.e. trying to have `asayac` as a total counter.  It won't work as [Neil Masson](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28175440/838992) notes, but even with that correction, it will be superslow, given the number of evaluations it will have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call asalmi, you set a local variable asayac to 0.  This should be a static variable, not a local one.

Answer (score 0):

c program to find the 10001st prime number

```
            #include<stdio.h>
            isPrime(int x){
                int i;
                for(i=2;i<=x/2;i++){
                    if(x%i==0) return 0;
                }
                return 1;
            }
            int main(){
                int n=3;
                int counter=1;
                while(counter!=10001){
                    if(isPrime(n)==1) counter++;
                    n=n+2; // possibility of next prime is by adding 2 to current 
                }
                printf("counter=%d\n",counter);
                printf("number is:%d\n",n-2); //-2 due to unwanted increment in loop

            }
```